# How do I find duplicates in an integer array and remove them?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, duplicates

I cannot use anything but an array (no lists or anything else).

I have an array: [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9]

That I want to make into: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]

Here's the code I have so far, but it's wrong. I want it to display the above array, but [here](http://puu.sh/kIv2F/556f6c90ed.png) is a screenshot of the actual output. Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

class arrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 3;
        array[4] = 5;
        array[5] = 6;
        array[6] = 7;
        array[7] = 7;
        array[8] = 9;
        array[9] = 9;

        Arrays.sort(array);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        int[] newArray = new int[array.length - count];
        for (int j = 1; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[j - 1]) {
                newArray[j] = array[j];
            } else {
                newArray[j - 1] = array[j - 1];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why no lists or any collection? Is this a homework?

Comment: Basic idea would nevertheless be: Create a second array, iterate over the first array in an outer loop, over the second in an inner loop and only add the item from the outer loop (the original array) if the inner loop (the new array) has not found that item.

Comment: Your second `for` loop needs **2** index counters, one for source array and one for destination array, because they "move" at different speed, i.e. source index always increases, but destination index only increases on new number.

Comment: *FYI:* Easier way to build source array: `int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9 };`

Comment: `Arrays.stream(array).distinct().sorted().toArray();` ?

Comment: @assylias Nice, but I would guess that Streams fall into the category of "anything else" in the *"I cannot use anything but an array (no lists or anything else)"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int[] deleteDuplicates(int[] input){

    int j = 0;
    int i = 1;
    if(input.length < 2){
        return input;
    }
    while(i < input.length){
        if(input[i] == input[j]){
            i++;
        }else{
            input[++j] = input[i++];
        }   
    }
    int[] output = new int[j+1];
    for(int k=0; k<output.length; k++){
        output[k] = input[k];
    }

    return output;
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/xjA3i3)**

Comment: That kind of worked. I have gotten a similar result before, but this just replaces the duplicates with 0's. As seen [here](http://puu.sh/kIvzP/289dcde6a5.png).

Comment: @ScottieJoe:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1.) Sort Array

2.) Remove duplicates and put inside `tempArray` using count variable, this will put zeroes in the last.

3.) Copy the content of this `tempArray` from `index 0 to count + 1` into new Array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 3;
        array[4] = 5;
        array[5] = 6;
        array[6] = 7;
        array[7] = 7;
        array[8] = 9;
        array[9] = 9;

        Arrays.sort(array);

        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];

        int prev = array[0];
        int count = 0;

         tempArray[count] = array[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
             if (prev != array[i]) {
                 count++;
                 tempArray[count] = array[i];
                }
                prev = array[i];
        }

        int[] finalArray = Arrays.copyOf(tempArray, count+1);// copies content from tempArray (0 to count + 1) index
        System.out.println(finalArray);
    }
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful why complex and what complex exactly, when you cannot use Collections API, just using Array, if you have simple solution, please post it, other can be befitted as well. We are still searching for simpler solution.

Comment: Check DaDaDom's comment in the question to know why yours is so poor and complex at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

Your second `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (i == 0 || array[i] != array[i - 1])
        newArray[j++] = array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 3;
    array[4] = 5;
    array[5] = 6;
    array[6] = 7;
    array[7] = 7;
    array[8] = 9;
    array[9] = 9;

   String arrayString =  Arrays.toString(array);
   for(int index =0 ; index <= arrayString.length(); index++){
      try{
          int number = Integer.parseInt(arrayString.charAt(index)+"");
          if(!stringBuffer.toString().contains(number+"")){
          if(stringBuffer.length()!=0)
              stringBuffer.append(",");
             stringBuffer.append(number);
          }

      }catch(Exception e){

      }
   }
   String[] stringArray = stringBuffer.toString().split(",");
   array = new Integer[stringArray.length];
   for(int index = 0 ; index < stringArray.length ; index++){
       array[index] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[index]); 
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

}

Is this helpful to you , can you check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = IntStream.of(array).distinct().toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several different things going on:

> Where am I going wrong?

```
        if (array[j] == array[j - 1]) {
            newArray[j] = array[j];
        } else {
            newArray[j - 1] = array[j - 1];
        }
```

This means that when `j` and `j-1` are equal, you are setting `j-1` to something, and `j` itself remains unchanged (a `0` by default int)...

Just change `newArray[j - 1] = array[j - 1];` to `newArray[j] = array[j - 1];`

Answer (score -1):

In your code ,you are looping the values in `array` by a length newArray.length, then the last part of  `array` will be lost .

Change

```
for (int j = 1; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[j - 1]) {
                newArray[j] = array[j];
            } else {
                newArray[j - 1] = array[j - 1];
            }
        }
```

to

```
        int index = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j< array.length - 1; j++){
                if(array[j] == array[j + 1]){
                    j++;
                }
                newArray[index++] = array[j];
        }
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a sequence of 3 or more duplicates.